# Obtener un solo valor de MySQL y almacenarlo en una variable con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, web

necesito ayuda para comprender algo básico. He buscado por todo lado pero las respuestas no han sido simples. 
He estado tratado de validar un tipo específico de usuario con 
ID_Perfil = 001 para que sea redireccionado a  "MenuExamenes.php" y usuarios con ID_Perfil= 002 que sean redireccionados a "MenuPrincipal.php." Realmente no sé si es posible hacer algo tan sencillo como almacenar un solo valor, obviando que va a almacenar el primer valor que encuentre...o el último. En este caso es un único valor por lo que no es importante.

ID_Perfil es en la BD un int(3).
(Sé que esta es la opción menos óptima para hacerlo, es para un proyecto de aprendizaje, no de la vida real).

Tengo un config.php:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:8889');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'ProgramaPruebas');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Y tengo mi login.php

```
 <?php
 include("config.php");
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

 $myusername =        mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['user_nickname']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 



  $sqlusertype = "SELECT ID_Perfil FROM Usuarios WHERE user_nickname =      '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword";
  $result1 = mysqli_query($sqlusertype, $db);


  $sql = "SELECT User_Id FROM Usuarios WHERE user_nickname =      '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
   $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);


    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);



if($count == 1 && result1 == 001 ) {



echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Inicio de Sesión Exitoso");
window.location.href="MenuExamenes.php";

</script>';

 alert("Inicio de Sesión Exitoso");

 }
 elseif($count == 1 && result1 == 002 ){
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("Inicio de Sesión Exitoso");
 window.location.href="MenuPrincipal.php";

 }else{
 $error = "El usuario/contraseña son incorrectos";
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no es clara, esto es casi un trabalengua: *Realmente no sé si es posible hacer algo tan sencillo como almacenar un solo valor, obviando que va a almacenar el primer valor que encuentre...o el último. En este caso es un único valor por lo que no es importante.* Por experiencia, la solución de un problema se dificulta porque ni siquiera somos claros **explicando** el problema. Plantéalo claramente y ya tendrás al menos el problema resuelto al 50%. Por cierto, hay un error de sintaxis en el `elseif`. Y, puede redirigir desde PHP sin Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Para extraer el resultado de la columna en cada consulta:

```
 $sqlusertype = "SELECT ID_Perfil FROM Usuarios WHERE user_nickname =      '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($sqlusertype, $db);
$id_perfil = -1;
if ($result1) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
        $id_perfil = $row['ID_Perfil'];
    }
} else {
    echo "error en la cosulta<br />";
}


 $sql = "SELECT User_Id FROM Usuarios WHERE user_nickname =      '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
 $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$user_id = -1;
if ($result) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $user_id = $row['User_Id'];
    }
} else {
    echo "error en la cosulta<br />";
}
```

Nota: tienes un error en:

```
echo '... window.location.href="MenuPrincipal.php";
```

puedes corregirlo añadiendo: ;'

```
echo '... window.location.href="MenuPrincipal.php";';
```

No es una buena práctica emplear javascript de esta manera para redirigir desde un script php. 
En todo caso puedes implementar este método:

```
header('Location: MenuPrincipal.php');

header('Location: /path/MenuPrincipal.php');
```

Esta expresión "result1 == 001" es lo mismo que "result1 == 1" ya que es un entero.
Si "ID_Perfil" o "User_Id" devuelve un entero no habrá ningún problema, pero si es un string, te aconsejo convertirlo en entero mediante esta función:

```
$user_id_int = intval($user_id);  

echo intval('001');  // devuelve 1
```

Haciendo esta conversión, ahora puedes cambiar la expresión a:

```
if($count == 1 & result1 === 1){...}
```

Es una buena práctica utilizar === en vez de == ya que te aseguras que solo es true si es un entero y no un string convertido a entero durante la evaluación de la expresión.

Te aconsejo que prepares las sentencias SQL con bind_param(); para evitar SQLinjection, errores de tipo y otros problemas, además de tener el código más limpio y legible.

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando el código para hacerlo lo mas legible posible queda de la siguiente forma:

1. simplificamos la consulta trayendo ambos campos en una sola consulta
2. obtenemos los datos en un objeto
3. evaluamos el valor del campo ID_Perfil
4. Redireccionamos al lugar que corresponde

---

```
<?

    //incluir archivo de configuración
    include("config.php");

    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['user_nickname']);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

    $sql = "SELECT User_Id,ID_Perfil FROM Usuarios WHERE user_nickname = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword";

    //ejecutar consulta contra la BD trayendo ambos campos en una sola consulta optimizando los recursos del servidor
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

        //obtenemos el registro completo del usuario con todos los campos en un objeto
        $r=mysqli_fetch_object($result);

        //evaluamos el ID_Perfil y redireccionamos
        //si almacenas datos enteros debes tratarlos como enteros (1,2) a menos que sean de tipo varchar ('001, '002')
        switch($r->ID_Perfil){
            case 1:
                header("Location: MenuExamenes.php");
            case 2:
                header("Location: MenuPrincipal.php");
        }
    }
```